Spring Security: HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) being converted to 403 (Forbidden)
I'm encountering an issue in my Spring Boot application where a custom UnauthorizedException I'm throwing with HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) status is being converted to HTTP 403 (Forbidden).
Here's the relevant part of my code:
throw new UnauthorizedException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.name(), "Unauthorized Access");
This is the log I'm seeing:
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception com.rh.rhdo.scheduling.common.exception.UnauthorizedException: Unauthorized Access
I'm using Spring Security in my application. How can I ensure that my HTTP 401 status is preserved and not converted to 403?
Any help or insight into why this conversion is happening and how to prevent it would be greatly appreciated.
I've tried using Spring Security's built-in exceptions:
Instead of using a custom UnauthorizedException, I used Spring Security's AuthenticationException.

Please share at least your Security configuration and your Custom exception handler code.
